# Two cURL requests showing the same data when loaded via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, mailchimp

I'm making two seperate cURL requests in the same php page. When I load the page by itself, it works as expected, with each request returning different, correct data.

However, when I load the page via AJAX, the second request shows the same data as the first. Why is this happening? Code follows below:

```
    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$api_key );
    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => $api_key,
    );
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ch2 = curl_init();

    $curlopt_url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/".$_GET['id'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $results = json_decode($result, true); ?>

    $curlopt_url_b = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/".$_GET['id'].'/sent-to/?count=5000 ';

    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url_b);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $recipient_result = curl_exec($ch2);
    $recipients = json_decode($recipient_result, true);
```

When loaded via AJAX, $recipients == $results, when they should return results from completely different end points. What gives?

Comment: You need to join the results and json_encode() once. What you doing with `$results` and `$recipients`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But why does it work when loaded on its own, rather than via AJAX?

Comment: Its not most likely you got 2 json objects if you look carfully `{}{}`, jquery will only parse one.

Comment: It could also be that if your querying say `/endpoint.php` jquery is caching the request, you could try `cache: false,` in your ajax call.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's one ajax call, with different variables for each of the cURL requests, so that can't be it either.

Comment: Found it - there was a bug cause by the AJAX request that was changing the cURL url requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the AJAX request, not the cURL request. The AJAX request had added an additional paramter to the URL (in this case, 'ajax=true'), which was feeding through into $_GET variable, and hence requesting the wrong endpoint. It loaded correctly when loaded independently because the URL was not changed by the JS.